# get items with no child relation or child with certain parameters

Tags: typeorm

how can i get all bookings with no payments or with payments with status pending.

Something like "whereDoesntHave" on Laravel

Thanks!

```
@Entity()
export class Booking extends BaseEntity{
                
    @Column({type: 'varchar', length: 10})
    code: string

    @OneToMany(() => Payment, Payment => Payment.booking, { cascade: true })
    payments: Payment

}

@Entity()
export class Payment extends BaseEntity {
    
  @ManyToOne(() => Booking, { nullable: false })
  booking: Booking
  
  @Column({ type: "float" })
  amount: number
  
  @Column()
  status: PaymentStatus;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add a foreign key to `Payment` entity called `bookId`:

```
@Entity()
export class Payment extends BaseEntity {

  @Column({nullable: true})
  bookId:number; 
    
  @ManyToOne(() => Booking, { nullable: false })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'bookId' }) // <= and add JoinColumn here
  booking: Booking
  
  @Column({ type: "float" })
  amount: number
  
  @Column()
  status: PaymentStatus;    
}
```

Then, you should get all bookings where `bookId` on `Payment` is null:

```
await Booking.find({
  relations:['payments'],
  where:[
    'payments.status': 'pending',
    bookId: null 
  ]    
})
```

`[]` in `where` represents `OR` in the query.